# The PowerShell script uploads all my values as 0 from an excel spreadsheet, i'm unsure why?

Tags: excel, database, powershell, object

sorry if this is a rookie question, bit new to this... I'm trying to upload data from a .csv file to an online table using JSON.

The script below is recognised, especially the string values, but the rest of the columns appear but every value is 0. Even the 'Computer Name' section, when it should be 'Computer-01'.

I'm not entirely sure what i've done wrong, but imagine it's something syntax related. I've tried swapping out the intergers with string, but that usually causes the '0' to disappear and it's just blank.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Thank you.

```
#SU tile
$data = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\file.csv" -Delimiter ','
$data | Select-Object @{
    Name = "Domain";
    Expression ={[string]$_.Domain}
},
@{
    Name = "Name";
    Expression ={[string]$_.Name}
},
@{
    Name = "Computer Name";
    Expression ={[int]$_.ComputerName}
},
@{
    Name = "IP Address";
    Expression ={[int]$_.IPAddress}
},
@{
    Name = "Approved Updates Installed";
    Expression ={[int]$_.ApprovedUpdatesInstalled}
},
@{
    Name = "Last Reported Status Date";
    Expression = {[LastReportedStatusDate]::ParseExact($($_.LastReportedStatusDate), 'dd/MM/yyyy',[Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB'))}
    },
@{
    Name = "Make";
    Expression = {[String]$_.Make}
}
```

I've tried swapping out the integers with string, but that usually causes the '0' to disappear and it's just blank.

I'm expecting the numbers on the spreadsheet, so 2,25,54 etc and ip addresses e.g. 123.11.23

Comment: There's no such thing as JSON code. Is this PowerShell code? then tag it PowerShell

Comment: Only pure numbers can be converted to `[int]`, if there are non-digit characters as in `Computer-01` you need to keep it as `[string]`. In this case you don't even need a conversion as CSV values are strings by default.

Comment: @zett42, thank you for replying that is good to know. Turns out I just didn't space the words in the expression for each header - schoolboy error, but all working now.